# Can't profile Babel-transpiled Node.js app with Spy-js in WebStorm

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, webstorm, profiler

So me and my team are currently in the process of profiling our Node.js app to try and improve performance on it as much as we can. After doing it with Chrome's DevTools for Node.js which was not excruciatingly hard to achieve, I thought of giving Jetbrains' [Spy-js](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/debugging-with-spy-js.html) a try and so far I've had no luck.

The app is run from inside a Docker container, and the code is transpiled with [babel-cli](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-cli) on the fly so this surely complicates things a bit. Even though I could probably get it working outside Docker and somehow connect it to the other containers, I could not go as far as to try that since I haven't managed to run the app with Spy-js.

Spy-js differs from DevTools in that it doesn't just connect with the app through the native inspector's debugging port, but rather requires the app to be run *from* the tool so that it can also intercept and modify script execution on the fly (as per their docs).

Since I'm using `babel-node` to run the app, I've tried creating a new Run/Debug configuration in WebStorm pointing to it (from a fresh global install of `babel-cli`) as the "Node interpreter" value in the options window. I've also already added all of the app's required environment variables to the options.

With the above setup, attempting to run the new Spy-js configuration results in the following errors:

```
Undefined handler Super
session (ak133): Error while instrumenting '<app directory here>/node_modules/p-locate/index.js'
 (g is not a function)
session (ak133): Unexpected identifier
<app directory here>/node_modules/boom/lib/index.js:249
    constructor(message, options undefined {}) {
                                 ^^^^^^^^^
```

Which looks like it's having trouble transpiling dependencies ([boom](https://github.com/hapijs/boom)). The original source for this was `options = {}` so I'm not sure why it would be converted to that either.

As much as I know this is not officially supported yet, I'd really appreciate being able to get it running *somehow* as Spy-js seems to do its own thing and isn't just another wrapper for the native v8 profiler, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `-r babel-register` instead of `babel-node` - does it make things any better?

[image]

Of course, you need adding `.babelrc` to your project, like

```
{
  "presets": ["env"]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort, this got me hopeful. Sadly the error message is the same, though.
One thing I did notice was that running it from a terminal seems to get the app running, but on Webstorm it's like it's trying to parse the code in a different manner. I do have a `.babelrc` there already, but I'm wondering whether Webstorm is making use of it at all.

Comment: it does; you must be using async stuff - error looks similar to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-30332

Comment: So hypothetically speaking if that was the case currently there would be no way around it? Also, that seems to relate to the first half of the errors, but I still also get the other with the misterious `undefined` in the transpilation.